# Access acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet method throws error

Tags: vba, ms-access

below is the code which i used to transfer the data from active sheet to access table '

it throws the following error

'  run time error 2498

```
Sub AccImport()
Dim acc As New Access.Application
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
'MsgBox (rng.Address)
acc.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\ksathis\Desktop\sample.accdb"
acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "RETOUCH_WORKEDHOURS", ActiveWorkbook.FullName, True, rng
acc.CloseCurrentDatabase
acc.Quit
Set acc = Nothing
End Sub
```

this is how my access table look

[image]

and this how my excel look sheet look
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range in TransferSpreadsheet is a string ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793(v=office.15).aspx ). You are using an object.

You may wish to consider :

```
Rng.Address
```